# IntelliJ debugging: Suspend whole VM then step on single thread

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, intellij-idea

I am debugging an application with lots of threads. My breakpoints are set to suspend the whole VM.

When a thread hits one of the breakpoints, I then want to use Step Over. But this appears to resume the whole VM, until that step completes.

It'd really help if I could step just the single thread that hit the breakpoint.

Is there any way to do this in IntelliJ 11.1 / Java 6? (Hope I'm not missing something obvious...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was added in IntelliJ 16 (the issue CrazyCoder referenced in his answer was resolved)

[image]

More details here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/02/intellij-idea-16-eap-improves-debugger-and-adds-git-worktree-support/

Comment: I have this check marked but when I resume, it still takes me to breakpoints in other threads that would also break there when I resume the thread I'm looking at. I'm ok with the deadlock risk since I'm already peering into the JVM. Any further tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

NetBeans can resume individual threads. While in debug mode, you can resume a thread from the left thread list by pressing a small button shaped like <kbd>Play</kbd> (►) near the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there's no such possibility because it may lead to deadlocks. You may vote for [IDEA-43728](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43728) though.

Comment: [IDEA-43728](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43728) was resolved in IntelliJ 16