# How to stay on the current thread while step-debugging in intellij

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-14

While debugging multi-threaded code in intellij, and more specifically while stepping inside a thread...

Setup:

```
            @Override
            public
            void run() {
                while (true) {
                  System.err.println("1" + get());  <-- breakpoint
                  System.err.println("2" + get());
                  System.err.println("3" + get());
                }
            }

            public String get() {
               return "x";
            }
```

I have 6 threads, all running the code above.

Intellij keeps changing the current thread that I'm in, meaning that when I issue a "Step over" (F8) command for T1, the debugger will change focus to T2. What I'm expecting is to stay in T1 *while* I'm debugging -- so to produce the result:

```
T1: 1x
T1: 2x
T1: 3x
T1: 1x
T1: 2x
```

Then, let's switch to another thread, T2.

```
T2: 1x
T2: 2x
T2: 3x
T2: 1x
T2: 2x
T2: 3x
```

Then, back to T1:

```
T1: 3x  (it picks back up from where it left off)
```

Instead, what I'm getting is:

```
T1: 1x
T3: 1x
T5: 1x
T1: 2x
T2: 1x
T3: 2x
T1: 3x
etc.
```

It's out-of-order, and **not at all** intuitive.

If I want to have my intended behavior, I have to do the following:

Switch to T1:

```
T1: 1x
```

Switch to T1:

```
T1: 2x
```

Switch to T1:

```
T1: 3x
```

Switch to T2:

```
T2: 1x
```

Switch to T2:

```
T2: 2x
```

Switch to T2:

```
T2: 3x
```

Switch to T1:

```
T1: 1x
```

etc...

I've searched for a way to prevent this, and I've not found a solution, and the only way that I've discovered (to maintain stepping in my current thread), is to keep selecting it with the mouse every time I step.

The question is: how do I do prevent intellij changing the thread I'm on?

edit: I should point out, that if any methods are called, thread execution order is out-of-order.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327576/intellij-debugging-suspend-whole-vm-then-step-on-single-thread

Comment: While related, I'm not interested in stopping the entire VM, and debugging at that point. My issue is that IDEA is skipping between threads during the debug process -- I just want it to stay in the current thread while stepping.

Comment: Looks like this might have been fixed 3 weeks ago in EAP 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, IDEA 15 (http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/06/intellij-idea-15-eap-is-open/) has fixed this issue.

Additionally, when a breakpoint is reached in another thread, there is a notification - which I found rather nice.

Answer (score 5):

You can right click on debug point, then assign a condition to only stop when reaching a given thread id. When running debug mode, the id can be gotten by using `Thread.currentThread().getId()`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By right click at the breakpoint dot, you can choose some options, e.g Suspend on Thread.

[image]

Comment: I've done this, it does not change anything. I should point out that if I change threads at all, it goes wonky again  (I'll update my question for this)

Comment: You can add a condition, which will check if you are using specific Thread. But it require from you explicit thread naming in the thread pool.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm wanting, as that would make sure the breakpoint is only valid for a specific thread -- I'm wanting to step through all of the threads, but to not change threads until I specify so. (I updated the question to provide more clarity on this)

Comment: You just want to do a code synchronously? You must know that the rule which maintain order of execution is related to specified ThreadPoolExecutor implementation. It's related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.   If I'm step debugging a single thread (out of many), I expect to stay in that thread until I explicitly choose to change threads (or the thread is suspended/dies/etc).  This is how Eclipse and Netbeans operate. Intellij works this way as long as you don't encounter any methods. When Intellij hits a method while step debugging, *whoooooop - time to switch threads!*

Answer (score 0):

From Intellij IDEA 16 onwards there'a new twist around this issue by resuming only the curent thread, and it can be tested [in the latest IDEA 16 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+16+EAP) by [enabling "debugger.step.resumes.one.thread" property in IDEA vmoptions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43728#comment=27-1286025)

Comment: Oh what a fun twist indeed.